# Design decisions in TodoMVC for Backbone Marionette example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, todomvc

I am wondering why in [TodoMVC Backbone Marionette](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/backbone_marionette), a `Marionette.Layout` was used for [`Footer`](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/backbone_marionette/js/TodoMVC.Layout.js#L35) instead of a simple `ItemView` like `Header`?

Also why use a `CompositeView` for [`TodoList.Views.ListView`](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/backbone_marionette/js/TodoMVC.TodoList.Views.js#L83) instead of a `CollectionView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any need for using a `Layout` in the footer. I think that the author thought that he maybe need to add some regions to the footer and he used a `Layout`, but in the actual implementation? No need.

About the `CompositeView` instead of `CollectionView`. The `CollectionView` doesn't allow you to have a template on it.

Imagine you need to show a list of clients but you don't want a simple `<ul>` to show the clients, you want some headers, some information and then the `<ul>` so with `CompositeView` you can add a template which can contain that header, information and of course the `<ul>`.

In that concrete case, he wants to show a checkbox with the list, so since he needs to show extra markup apart from the `<ul>` he needs a `CompositeView` to be able to add a template.

**TL;DR** Use a `CollectionView` if you don't need extra markup and if so, use a `CompositeView`